# How to create A4-sized hex paper with numbered hexes?

Tags: tools, map-making, maps, hexagonal-mapping

I'd like to draw a setting map on hex paper **with numbered hexes** for the purposes of hexcrawling. A google search resulted in several sources for hex papers without the numbering.

To be more explicit, I'd like to have:

- Paper size A4. If I can use some more obscure paper size with only minor distortions when I print it as A4, then that is also okay.
- Filled with hexes, up to the margins.
- The hexes are numbered in a reasonable way, so that in my (electronic) notes I can write that a city is in hex 11.15 or 4b or whatever the notation happens to be.
- Empty hex paper.
- Superimposed larger hexes would be a nice option, and would not be a problem, but are not a necessity.

My relevant computer skills are restricted to Geogebra, which is not immediately useful (AFAIK). Free software is preferable to commercial one; I can learn how to use new software, if necessary.

How can I create a hex map as desired above?

Comment: I am voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a shopping question ("where can I get...?").   You'll probably be better off asking this question in one of our [recommended forums](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go).  On the other hand, if you narrow this question down to only "how can I create numbered hex paper?" it might become answerable within site guidelines.

Comment: How *many* hexes per page? (*Pro Tip:* One hex is easy! `;-)`)

Comment: I interpreted the question to allow for an answer of "make your own", and answered it below on that basis.

Comment: @LegendaryDude That's fair; guidelines for how to create the necessary hex paper are acceptable answers to the question as is. Does a question count as a shopping question even when no shops exist?

Comment: @HeyICanChan One hex would make a poor overland map for hexcrawling purposes.

Comment: @LegendaryDude Specified "how to create" also in question body.

Comment: By the end, this reads as a software recommendation question. Despite asking “how”, answers *will* be either “I recommend downloading this PDF hex paper”, or “I recommend this software/online generator to do that”. There is not much room for “how” answers that aren't product recommendations. On the plus side, this is well-specified and, [with a few more easy details](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336), would seem to be on-topic for [softwarerecs.se] SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you experiment a bit, you can probably get what you want from http://zho.berka.com/goodies/hex/ - this is a hexmap generator oriented toward the Traveller rpg, and will use the Traveller coordinate system ccrr where cc is the column number and rr is the row number, with the upper left corner being 0101.

On my screen, setting a page width of 798 gets me 8.5 inches, so 780 should get you A4 width. At 798 and a hex side length of 30, I get approximately 17.5 columns of hexes - staggered/interlaced - across the page.

Again, you'll need to experiment a bit to find the right settings for your needs, but you should be able to come up with something that's adequate for your needs.

Comment: Any idea about the units in the parameters "width" and "height"? That would replace tedious experimentation with trivial arithmetic.

Comment: @Thanuir They're straight-up pixels, unquestionably - but the problem is that different screens and different printers will have different pixel densities.